# How to get response from interface method in adapter in android

Tags: java, android, interface, adaptor

So here I am calling the interface method from the adapter class. I want to update the `List` based on the user's input. How would I achieve it?

**Adapter class:**

```
public class ToDoListAdaptor extends SectionRecyclerViewAdapter < SectionHeader, Action, SectionViewHolder, ChildViewHolder > {

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(final ChildViewHolder holder, final int sectionPosition, final int childPosition, final Action child) {

        Context mainActivityContext = Constants.getContext();

        if (action_id.equals("pain")) {

            if (mainActivityContext != null && mainActivityContext instanceof MainActivity) {
                interfaceAdapter = ((HealthVitalsFunction) mainActivityContext);
                boolean result = interfaceAdapter.openPainRecordDialog(context, dbHelper, action_id, action_cat_id, action_plan_id, action_name);

                if (result)
                    update(sectionHeaderList, childPosition);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

The problem is that I am not able to call update() when user done with input.

**edit:**

```
@Override
    public boolean openPainRecordDialog(final Context context, final DbHelper dbHelper, final String action_id, final String action_cat_id, final String action_plan_id, final String action_name) {


        Constants.painData=false;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View mView = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.pain_record, null);


        final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(mView)
                .setTitle("")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null) 
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create();




        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {

                Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // TODO Do something

                        if (dialog != null && ((AlertDialog) dialog).isShowing()) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                        Constants.painData = true;


                    }
                });

                Button negativeButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                negativeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // TODO Do something

                        if (dialog != null && ((AlertDialog) dialog).isShowing()) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }

                        Constants.painData = false;
                    }

                });

            }
        });



        // show it
        dialog.show();

        return Constants.painData;

    }
```

Comment: are you using a dialog fragment which popup on click item of recyclerview?

Comment: I am using AlertDialog class to show the custom dialog. @Darish

Comment: does the alertDialog popup properly as you wish?

Comment: yes. it is working fine. When I am moving recycleview up and down, then the status is updating. But I want to change status instantly @Darish

Comment: post `openPainRecordDialog` code

Comment: @KishoreJethava update.

Comment: Just call `update(sectionHeaderList, childPosition)` inside positive click of dialog

Comment: not working @KishoreJethava

Comment: What's happening?

Comment: @KishoreJethava nothing happen. Calling update() but no changes effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to update the list based on the user's input.

If you are using a custom dialog, provide custom interface callback which defines `onSuccess()` method and implement it in your calling activity, which can be used to update the recyclerView. cheers :)

Comment: after updating the data list, just call the notifydatasetchanged method

Comment: can you provide the example how I do it. @Darish

Comment: use a custom dialog fragment, then pass a callback to the constructor..